# Using htaccess to rewrite a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change the URL of two specific pages in my application:

`app.mysite.com/thanks/type/b/` changes to `app.mysite.com/thanks/buyer/`

and

`app.mysite.com/thanks/type/s/` changes to `app.mysite.com/d/thanks/supplier/`

What would be the appropriate rewrite statement?

Comment: For clarity, what does *changes to* mean. What you the URL will be or what it is?

Comment: the url is currently app.mysite.com/thanks/type/b/ and I want it to change to app.mysite.com/thanks/buyer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^thanks/type/b/?$ thanks/buyer/
RewriteRule ^thanks/type/s/?$ d/thanks/supplier/
```

Comment: I believe you have this backwards based on the comments.

Comment: the url is currently app.example.com/thanks/type/b/ and needs to be rewritten to app.example.com/thanks/buyer/  ....  is it backwards?

Comment: @Eric, no it's not backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The follow should do what you want and allows an optional trailing slash, (i.e. `/thanks/buyer` or `/thanks/buyer/`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^thanks/buyer/?$ /thanks/type/b/
RewriteRule ^d/thanks/supplier/?$ /thanks/type/s/
```

Comment: the trailing slash will always there.  does the below answer not work if there is no trailing slash?

Comment: @Eric, you can remove the `?` if you want to force the trailing slash. @Tom, I think this is the right way based on the comments.